# C, free sub-list element by element causes unexpected behavior

Tags: c, free

I have a a linked list inside another linked list, typedefs are the following:

```
typedef struct struct_execution_queue {

    list_run_str *runstr;
    list_run_str *marker; //just a pointer to a specific element in runstr (it was not allocated with `malloc()`)

    int excount;

    struct struct_execution_queue *next;
}list_ex;
```

`list_run_str` is another linked list:

```
typedef struct struct_run_str { //run element
    char car;
    struct struct_run_str *next;
    struct struct_run_str *prev;
} list_run_str;
```

I implemented an `insert()` method that creates a new `list_ex` element and insert it in the head of the list. I tried to run a simple test code to see if memory management was ok:

```
int main(){
/*read data from input file and insert into lists (this part is ok)
I have all data I need: two rheads and two markers
*/
list_ex *exhead = NULL;

exhead = insert(exhead, rheadone, markerone, 10);
exhead = insert(exhead, rheadtwo, markertwo, 20);

free_ex_list(exhead);

}
```

To free all `exhead` elements I need to free the relative sublist first.
Since `rhead` (sublist of `exhead`) is a linked list too (allocated with `malloc()`), I think it sould be freed element by element. This is the code I use:

```
void free_run_str_list(list_run_str *head) { //free a list_run_str list
    list_run_str *tmp;

    while (head != NULL) {
        tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
    } // <--------------------- breackpoint triggered here
}

void free_ex_list(list_ex *head) { //free a list_ex list
    list_ex *tmp;

    while (head != NULL) {
        tmp = head;
        free_run_str_list(tmp->runstr);
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

**The problem is** when I compile this code, Visual Studio triggers a break point in the indicated line. When I debug step by step, the code runs until  `free_run_str_list(tmp->runstr);` enters the call and does the first `free(tmp)`. Now `tmp` has random values inside it (as it sould be) but also `head` has the same random values and, at the second iteration, the line `free(temp)` tries to free already freed memory causing (i guess) the error to occur.

**So my questions are:**

1. Why this happens?
2. Does it means an error while allocating memory? (if this is the case i leave the insert code below)
3. Is this the right way to free `exhead`?

I searched for similar solutions but I think I have a different issue.

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363688/c-unable-to-free-memory-allocated-within-a-linked-list-structure) the issue was `malloc()` not allocating enough space for terminating character (not my case: i have a liked list of chars as sublist, not a string pointer).
- Not shure why but if I replace `free_run_str_list(tmp->runstr);` with `free(tmp->runstr)` in `free_ex_list()` no break points are triggered (but I am not shure this is the proper way: free only the head of the sub-linked list?).

Insert code:

```
list_ex *insert(list_ex *exhead, list_run_str *rhead, list_run_str *marker, int count) {
    list_ex *tmp;
    list_run_str *tmphead, *tmpmarker;

    if ((tmp = (list_ex *)malloc(sizeof(list_ex)))) {

        tmphead = duplicate(rhead, marker, &tmpmarker);
        tmp->runstr = tmphead;
        tmp->marker = tmpmarker;

        tmp->excount = count;

        tmp->next = exhead;
        exhead = tmp;
    }
    else
        printf("insert mem error\n");
    return tmp;
}



list_run_str *duplicate(list_run_str *head, list_run_str *marker, list_run_str **newmarker) { //duplicate a list_run_str_list and the relative marker
    list_run_str *newhead, *newtmphead, *tmphead;
    int markerpos, len, i;

    //find list length
    for (len = 0, tmphead = head; tmphead != NULL; len++, tmphead = tmphead->next);

    //find marker position in head
    markerpos = 0;
    if (marker != NULL)
        for (tmphead = marker; tmphead->prev != NULL; markerpos++, tmphead = tmphead->prev);

    //create new list_run_str list
    if ((newhead = (list_run_str *)malloc(sizeof(list_run_str) * len))) {
        i = 0;
        //load the new head
        newtmphead = newhead;
        tmphead = head;

        (newtmphead + i)->prev = NULL;
        (newtmphead + i)->next = (newtmphead + i + 1);
        (newtmphead + i)->car = tmphead->car;

        //load other elements
        for (i++, tmphead = tmphead->next; tmphead != NULL; i++, tmphead = tmphead->next) {
            (newtmphead + i)->car = tmphead->car;
            (newtmphead + i)->next = (newtmphead + i + 1);
            (newtmphead + i)->prev = (newtmphead + i - 1);
        }
        ((newtmphead)+len - 1)->next = NULL;

        //update the new marker
        for (i = 0, newtmphead = newhead; i < markerpos; i++, newtmphead = newtmphead->next);
        *newmarker = newtmphead;
    }
    else
        printf("duplicate mem error\n");
    return newhead;
}
```

Thanks for help.

**EDIT**

here is the exact code that causes the issue, i tried to simplify it as much as i could.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct struct_run_str {
    char car;
    struct struct_run_str *next;
    struct struct_run_str *prev;
} list_run_str;

typedef struct struct_execution_queue {
    list_run_str *runstr; //this will be allocated with malloc()
    list_run_str *marker; //this is only a pointer to a certain element in runstr

    int excount;

    struct struct_execution_queue *next;
}list_ex;

void free_run_str_list(list_run_str *head) { //free a "list_run_str" list
    list_run_str *tmp;

    while (head != NULL) {
        tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

void free_ex_list(list_ex *head) { //free a "list_ex" list
    list_ex *tmp;

    while (head != NULL) {
        tmp = head;
        free_run_str_list(tmp->runstr);
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

list_run_str *loadrunstr(list_run_str *head, char c) { //add an item at the ed of a "list_run_str" list
    list_run_str *tmp, *tmphead;

    if ((tmp = (list_run_str *)malloc(sizeof(list_run_str)))) {
        tmp->car = c;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL) {
            tmp->prev = NULL;
            head = tmp;
        }
        else {
            for (tmphead = head; tmphead->next != NULL; tmphead = tmphead->next);
            tmphead->next = tmp;
            tmp->prev = tmphead;
        }
    }
    else
        printf("loadrunstr mem error\n");
    return head;
}

list_run_str *duplicate(list_run_str *head, list_run_str *marker, list_run_str **newmarker) { //duplicte head to newhed and adjust newmarker
    list_run_str *newhead, *newtmphead, *tmphead;
    int markerpos, len, i;

    //find list length
    for (len = 0, tmphead = head; tmphead != NULL; len++, tmphead = tmphead->next);

    //find marker position
    markerpos = 0;
    if (marker != NULL)
        for (tmphead = marker; tmphead->prev != NULL; markerpos++, tmphead = tmphead->prev);

    //create new "list_run_str" list
    if ((newhead = (list_run_str *)malloc(sizeof(list_run_str) * len))) {
        i = 0;
        //load the head
        newtmphead = newhead;
        tmphead = head;

        (newtmphead + i)->prev = NULL;
        (newtmphead + i)->next = (newtmphead + i + 1);
        (newtmphead + i)->car = tmphead->car;

        //load the other elements
        for (i++, tmphead = tmphead->next; tmphead != NULL; i++, tmphead = tmphead->next) {
            (newtmphead + i)->car = tmphead->car;
            (newtmphead + i)->next = (newtmphead + i + 1);
            (newtmphead + i)->prev = (newtmphead + i - 1);
        }
        ((newtmphead)+len - 1)->next = NULL;

        //update new marker position
        for (i = 0, newtmphead = newhead; i < markerpos; i++, newtmphead = newtmphead->next);
        *newmarker = newtmphead;
    }
    else
        printf("duplicate mem error\n");
    return newhead;
}

list_ex *insert(list_ex *exhead, list_run_str *rhead, list_run_str *marker, int count) { //insert new element in the head of a "list_ex" list
    list_ex *tmp;
    list_run_str *tmphead, *tmpmarker;

    if ((tmp = (list_ex *)malloc(sizeof(list_ex)))) {

        tmphead = duplicate(rhead, marker, &tmpmarker);
        tmp->runstr = tmphead;
        tmp->marker = tmpmarker;

        tmp->excount = count;

        tmp->next = exhead;
        exhead = tmp;
    }
    else
        printf("insert mem error\n");
    return tmp;
}

int main() {
    list_ex *exhead;
    list_run_str *rheadone, *markerone, *rheadtwo, *markertwo;

    exhead = NULL;
    rheadone = NULL;
    rheadtwo = NULL;

    //load some items in rheadone
    rheadone = loadrunstr(rheadone, 'a');
    rheadone = loadrunstr(rheadone, 'b');
    rheadone = loadrunstr(rheadone, 'c');

    //load some items in rheadtwo
    rheadtwo = loadrunstr(rheadtwo, 'd');
    rheadtwo = loadrunstr(rheadtwo, 'e');
    rheadtwo = loadrunstr(rheadtwo, 'f');

    //set markerone to point at some char in rheadone
    markerone = rheadone->next; //points to 'b'

    //set markertwho to point at some char in rheadtwo
    markertwo = rheadtwo; //points to 'd'

    //insert two new elements into exhead
    exhead = insert(exhead, rheadone, markerone, 10);
    exhead = insert(exhead, rheadone, markerone, 20);

    //try to free them
    free_ex_list(exhead);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Preferably as a single block of code. And that should include all variables and also all input data you feed to the program. If possible, make a simplified input handlinmg, using some static compile-time fixed input that leads to the problem (also [read about finding a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/)). And of course [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: "Visual Studio triggers a break point". I dont think you mean that. I think you mean that you get an error message.Cam you please include the message

Comment: @pm100 Visual Studio does break (as in, interrupt execution) when it detects certain kinds of problems via assertions or fences, so I suspect this is what he's referring to. Knowing the message that appears in Visual Studio would still be helpful though.

Comment: @Some programmer dude,  ok working on it

Comment: @pm 100, thanks for reply, this is all i get from VS, sorry the language is italian: https://ibb.co/jKfL39

Comment: @TypeIA 'break point' in an IDE has a very specific meaning. This is not it

Comment: What is `rheadone` (and the other three variables in `main`) ?

Comment: edited my question, hope my code is clear enough

Comment: In `duplicate()`, you allocated an array with a single `malloc` and you are trying to `free` the elements individually in `free_run_str_list()`. You should only `free` exactly what you `malloc`ed.

Comment: @IanAbbott, so I need to change the whole code of free_sun_str_list() with free(head) because I allocated all the memory at once? (my questions could soud stupid but I'm a student and I'm trying to understand how memory managment works...thanks.)

Comment: You cannot allocate a list element-by-element and then "duplicate" it by allocating an entire array of elements and then pretend you have a well defined data type. If you want to define a linked list or any other data type, decide on *one* way to allocate it and *one* way to free it.

Comment: Basically, you cannot `free` the middle of a block allocated by `malloc`. You can only `free` the start of the block, and it frees the whole block that was allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: You are writing out of bounds in the `duplicate` function. That destroys the value of `newmarker`

Comment: @pm100 I understood perfectly what the OP meant and I don't think anything is to be gained by terminological pedantry in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your posted code, the problem is in function `duplicate`. It sets variable `len` to the length of the list to be duplicated, and calls `malloc` to allocate a block of `len` elements of `list_run_str`.  It then fills in those elements and joins them together into a linked list of `list_run_str`, does some other stuff and returns a pointer to the first element.

Presumably, the return value of function `duplicate` ends up in the `runstr` member of a `list_ex`.

Your `free_run_str_list` function called from `free_list_ex` calls `free` on each item of the linked list. If this linked list was constructed by function `duplicate` then the first call to `free` will free the entire block. However, you are freeing each item of the linked list individually even though they were all allocated from a single call to `malloc`.

To fix it, you should change your `duplicate` function to `malloc` each item of the linked list individually, since that is what the `free_run_str_list` function expects.